# .collapsed , [collapsed="true"]

Tags: css

I am working on a project. And in one of the css files it quotes:

```
    .collapsed, [collapsed="true"] {
       display: none;
    }
```

My question here is what does "collapsed= true" mean? And how does this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CSS, `[collapsed="true"]` will target an element with the `collapsed` attribute set as `true`.

[Here is an example using HTML.](http://jsbin.com/lafec/1/edit) The collapsed attribute is not valid HTML markup, this is just for illustration.

Only the `<div>` with collapsed set to "true" will be selected.

```
<div collapsed="true"></div>
```

This snippet:

```
.collapsed, [collapsed="true"] {
   display: none;
}
```

will target all elements with the class of `collapsed`,  as well as elements with the collapsed attribute set to "true", and remove them from view with `display: none`.

---

[More information on the collapsed attribute (in XUL):](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/collapsed)

> If true, then the element is collapsed and does not appear. It is equivalent to setting the CSS visibility property to collapse.

**Note:** The only reference to the collapsed attribute I can find is in relation with [XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL)

> XUL (XML User Interface Language) is Mozilla's XML-based language for building user interfaces of applications like Firefox. The term XUL is sometimes used to refer to the whole Mozilla platform (e.g. XUL applications are applications using XUL and other components of the platform).